# Mtkclient | mediatek phone won't boot into brom/boot rom mode

Tags: applications, google-play-store, rooting, motorola, mediatek

I downloaded mtkclient from the GitHub and followed the installation instructions but when I plug my phone in after running the command it never recognizes my phone. I've tried all different types of button combos and none seem to work. My phone is a Moto g 5g 2022 codenamed Austin and it is a mediatek dimensity 700.

Comment: When talking about tools like "mtkclient" that are not part of Android or Android SDK please always include the lik to the tool in your question. You should also explain detail at which step your phone is not recognized.

Comment: Ok yes, so my phone is not being recognized during the part where it says to plug your phone in and hold the buttons down. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to Motorola disabling the ability to boot into brom mode on newer Mediatek devices. I have the Moto G 5G 2022(Metro PCS) and I have unlocked the bootloader and rooted with Magisk, I think that the issue is due to a setting on the kernel command line, but I have been unable to recompile the kernel so far, so I can't be 100% sure. Long story short, as of right now the only way I know for sure to get into brom mode is to crack open the case and ground some test points, but since I have no idea which ones to do I would highly recommend against this.

Comment: have you found any custom roms or gsis that work with this phone? I tried some but they lacked any good features that im looking for. would like a pixel experience